# USB Bluetooth with non-Bluetooth supported devices

Tags: usb, bluetooth, connection

How does Bluetooth work with older devices? For example, can a USB x.0 Bluetooth wireless mouse plug into any laptop with a USB x.0 port and connect the mouse to the laptop wirelessly, regardless if the laptop has "Bluetooth support?"

Comment: You really need to clarify what you want to actually accomplish, otherwise there are likely a number of caveats. That said, if the USB dongle is specifically made for that mouse, then the Bluetooth elements are likely  inside the mouse and dongle, and whether the computer supports Bluetooth version X is probably irrelevant. A bigger issue might be drivers for the dongle itself.

Comment: USB version is irrelevant and unrelated to Bluetooth, and even if it were the bandwidth of Bluetooth is well below that used by *any* version of USB. If you have a Bluetooth mouse and Bluetooth on your computer so long as your computer Bluetooth drivers support the correct [profiles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles) then it will work regardless.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Sorry, I should have clarified more. I did mean that the mouse and Bluetooth dongle were specifically made for each other, my main concern was would it work with a laptop or device that didn't have any sort of Bluetooth built-in. Or a better way to ask my question might be: what is required for Bluetooth to work. Any sort of Bluetooth programming in the laptop?